# C# call a method from an interface with no defining code

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

Alright, so I'm new to C# Interfaces. From my understanding, an interface contains method prototypes that a class can implement and use. For example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    public void printhelloworld();
}

class MyExampleClass : MyInterface {
    public void exampleMethod() {
        printhelloworld();
    }

    public void printhelloworld() {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

However, the Interface I'm having trouble with is in `Shell32`. More specifically, I'm trying to call the [`ParseName` method of `Folder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787882(v=vs.85).aspx) and, from there, the [`InvokeVerb` method of `FolderItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787816(v=vs.85).aspx).

From what I'm seeing in the Class View, `Shell32` has declarations for:

- An Interface, `Folder`
- Another Interface, `FolderItem`
- A class, `ShellFolderItemClass`, that cannot be inherited from

My goal is to invoke a right-click verb on certain directories. However, from what I'm seeing, *interfaces require an implementation*, meaning that I can't just simply "call the method." The method isn't defined.

How would I make that work?

Comment: For a start your `MyExampleClass` doesn't implement the interface `MyInterface`. Your class would need to be defined as `class MyExampleClass : MyInterface`

Comment: Furthermore, the visibility in the interface implicitly is `internal`, while the visibility in the implementation is `public`.

Comment: @Codor I put the code up as an example of interface implementation. I posted the question in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM interfaces work differently than normal C# types. Casting a COM instance to an interface invokes `QueryInterface`. This is CLR magic.

That's why you can make interface casts work on COM types that statically shouldn't work. Also, casts can fail that normally wouldn't fail.

I have no experience with the Shell COM API but theoretically `(MyInterface)(new MyExampleClass())` can work if all types involved are COM types.

Comment: You can also use `new MyInterface()` for COM interfaces. Silly compiler magic that lets you "new" a COM interface.